# Comparing if lists are same in python when they have different braces

Tags: python

so i have two lists of IP's both are same but when i  run if condition on them them, it is showing they are not equal, as they have different braces i am not sure how to solve this as i am getting theses values from web requests from BOTO3

```
ip_list_ips = {'54.183.255.128/26', '15.177.16.0/21', '54.245.168.0/26'}
sg_rule_ips = ['54.183.255.128/26', '15.177.16.0/21', '54.245.168.0/26']

if ip_list_ips == sg_rule_ips:
   print("lists are same ")
else:
   print("not same")
```

here it always returns as not same,
it is because of different braces, if just run this line by changing "{" to "[", it works and i don't know how to proceed because i get these variables by sending API requests and filtering the output

Comment: `{` indicates a set, which you could sort and convert to a list

Comment: The question is, do you know what these "different braces" mean? I think there's no point in attempting to solve this in terms of "different braces".

Comment: @ForceBru agree